# 422 response using httpPost gives back {"response":{}} instead of the actual API response

Tags: javascript, networking, promise, http-post, es6-promise

if I run curl `localhost:4000/myserver`, I get:
`{error: "foo"}`

```
//MyAPI
function create(){
 return httpPost('localhost:4000/myserver', myParams);
}
```

and call it with:

```
return MyApi.create(config, params).then(res => {
    console.log("Full success" + JSON.stringify(res));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Full error" + JSON.stringify(err));
  })
```

The console log shows only `Full error{"response":{}}`, which does not match my cURL.

How do I get the full error and response body?

Comment: You mean `JSON.parse`, not `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working with asynchronous calls, in most cases (if your framework doesn't do it automatically), you have to parse the response to get the data you can work with further, use [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_parse.asp) for that.

Here is an example of what's really happening (if you receive data from a web server, the data is always a **string** type):

```js
// Fake response
const response = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}';
console.log('typeof response:', typeof response);

// Parsing the response
const parsed = JSON.parse(response);
console.log('typeof parsed:', typeof parsed);
console.log('parsed:', parsed);
```